# Problem in redirection in php

Tags: php

I am creating subdomain by php code and further want to redirect on subdomain but i am redirected to

http://sssssswwwwww.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

I am not understating why am i getting his error but when i am opening it directly this is opening well without any problem. Why am i not redirecting during creation of subdomains ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your host needs to 'catch up' with your requests. When I create a new subdomain under CPanel, it takes about 1-5 minutes before changes are reflected.

Though, this depends on how you're creating the subdomain from PHP (I'm assuming an API of some sort)

Comment: I m creating subdomain by php acript dynamically and this is creating well but i m not rederiting to subdomain going to ddeafult error page